# How to assign new key on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

s,d and g keys do not work on my keyboard. I would like to assign these keys to key combinations of other keys. For example pressing x key two times pretends like s key. Is there any software or windows settings does that ?

Comment: It would make more sense for you to repair your keyboard or buy a new one.

Comment: This is laptop keyboard. I tried to fix it however I could not disassembly enough to reach keyboard. Computer repairmen ask me to pay about $100 for fixing it. Laptop itself worth $300

Comment: Hilarious, "pressing *x* two times to get *s* key".  And so what happens if you actually want two *x* characters in a row?  This is about the funniest question I've seen here.  But in all seriousness, pay the $ to sort this out.  You'll drive yourself nuts dealing with shortcuts like that.

Comment: Buy a USB keyboard and use that: you can use an on-screen keyboard for the occasions when you don't have it with you.

Comment: What make and model of laptop is it? Ebay has loads of replacement keyboards, they are fairly easy to replace even for a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recenlty I realized that we can type characters with their ASCII code using ALT key.

Lets say we would like to type "s" character. If you type 0115 at numpad while holding ALT key will type "s" key.
You can do ALT + 0100 for "d".

You can see the full list [here](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

on Windows, download Microsoft Keyboard layout creator MSKLC.exe and run that

After running that, you can assign any key combination to give screen output of other keys. with control, Shift, Alt, think of a combination which is not in use in windows defaults anywhere or in any software. mostly Right Alt is used which is called AltGr.

say, use AltGr w to get s, AltGr e to get d, use AltGr r to get f, These are just above your missing keys, so would be easier to handle.

save that layout, then onwards you need not keep MSKLC.exe running. install this layout to make it your default layout. and you will not notice any difference in entire keyboard other than these 3 key combinations.

Thanks.